# how to run qt widget pyqtgraph from python app

Tags: python, pyside, pyqtgraph

I have well running python app with GUI made on tkinter. I need to implement qt widget from pyqtgraph showing graph (massive data so matplot lib can't do that).
I import needed Qt stuff:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
```

and following code somewhere from tkinter class opens it in new window and shows the graph:

```
def preview_show():
    APP = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ## Define a top-level widget to hold everything
    win = QtGui.QWidget()
    ## Create a grid layout to manage the widgets size and position
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    win.setLayout(layout)

    pl = pg.PlotWidget()
    pl.plot(self.DataSeries, pen=(255, 0, 0), name="Red curve")
    layout.addWidget(pl)

    win.show()
    APP.exec_()
```

Then, this widget has some functions accessible by right-clicking on the graph and I need them (like exporting image). But when I try to click on any of that functions - python kernel crashes with error code 255. I have an idea that qt events are not processed. So I tried to call Qt event handler in a loop from python, instead of calling APP.exec_():

```
while TRUE:
    APP.processEvents()
    time.sleep(0.002)
```

but it runs the same way (window with graph opens but freezes on attempt to access other built-in functions).
I was thinking about running Qt widget in separate thread but if I can't do this in a loop then I think it will not run in the thread either.

I've read this [Python working with Qt, event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716230/python-working-with-qt-event-loop) but it doesn't work for me.

So the question is - how to process Qt widget from tkinter app correctly (in a separate window) with all built-in functions running? Am I right that the problem caused by wrong qt events handling from tkinter app?

Comment: you can not and should not combine libraries that handle GUIs, since both libraries have an evenloop (Qt: `app.exec_()`, tk: `root.mainloop()`) that are essentially a while True that allows them to check OS events and the user, so the blocking of that eventloop implies that the application freezes. So the solution is: implement your GUI with Qt or do not use pyqtgraph.

Comment: Thank you, eyllanesc for fast answer! Can I then start Qt widget from tkinter as a new app and pass my arguments? If there is simple solution of course. I do not need to get anything back from this widget back to tkinter app.

Comment: No, the correct solution is to convert to Qt your tkinter code, another possibility is that you launch 2 scripts, and that you communicate both scripts by a socket. Another possibility is to call the second script with subprocess.call() and pass the arguments to it.